# Object doesn't support property or method 'removeClass'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to do a simple removeClass and addClass to change styles on an Img.

```
    <div id="Pic_Viewer">
        <div id="Main_Pic_Viewer">
                <div class="Not_Selected" >
                    <img src='#' alt="PicURL_1" />
                </div>
                <div class="Not_Selected" >
                    <img src='#' alt="PicURL_2" />
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Small_Pic_Viewer">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img class="Small_Pic" src'#' alt="PicURL_1" />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img class="Small_Pic" src='#' alt="PicURL_2" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried doing this with the #Main_Pic_Viewer img inside div and without.

js:

```
$('#Small_Pic_Viewer ul li').click(
        function () {
            var ThisLI = this.firstElementChild.alt;
            var BigImgDiv = $('#Main_Pic_Viewer div');
            var CurDiv;

            for (var i = 0, l = BigImgDiv.length; i < l; i++) {
                CurDiv = BigImgDiv[i];
                if (BigImgDiv[i].children[0].alt === ThisLI) {
                    CurDiv.removeClass('Not_Selected').addClass('Selected');
                } else {
                    CurDiv.removeClass('Selected');
                };
            };
        }
    );
```

Not sure why im getting this error message, as removeClass() is working fine in other methods.

Comment: Because it's not a jQuery object, simply do `CurDiv = $(BigImgDiv[i]);`

Comment: Thank you all, answered completly evaded me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using a numeric index in a jQuery object you get the original DOM element(s) without the jQuery wrapper.

Just wrap this again in a jQuery function and you'll be fine:

```
// ...

CurDiv = $( BigImgDiv[i] );

// ...
```

Another solution as suggested by @Andreas in the comments is to use the [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, which is probably the better way:

```
// ...

CurDiv = BigImgDiv.eq(i);

// ...
```

Comment: Why unwrap the dom element to instantly wrap it again in an jQuery object? Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Yx5c8/1/

```
$('#Small_Pic_Viewer ul li').click(function () {
    var ThisLI = this.firstElementChild.alt;
    $('#Main_Pic_Viewer div').each(function () {
        if (this.children[0].alt === ThisLI) {
            $(this).removeClass('Not_Selected').addClass('Selected');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('Selected');
        }
    });
});
```